# eigenvalues of a general complex matrix in C++

Tags: linear-algebra, c++

Is there a free C or C++ library including a routine for the eigenvalues of a general complex matrix? I checked a number of linear algebra packages like Eigen, but there does not seem to be support for complex matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eigen can compute eigenvalues of a complex matrix. Take a look at this documentation page:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ComplexEigenSolver.html

Here is an Eigen version of a Lapack, zgeev example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues> 

void complexEigenproblem()
{
  const int n = 4;
  Eigen::MatrixXcd a(n, n);
  typedef std::complex<double> C;
  a <<
    C(-3.97, -5.04), C(-4.11, 3.70), C(-0.34, 1.01), C(1.29, -0.86),
    C(0.34, -1.50), C(1.52, -0.43), C(1.88, -5.38), C(3.36, 0.65),
    C(3.31, -3.85), C(2.50, 3.45), C(0.88, -1.08), C(0.64, -1.48),
    C(-1.10, 0.82), C(1.81, -1.59), C(3.25, 1.33), C(1.57, -3.44);
  Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXcd> ces;
  ces.compute(a);
  std::cout << "The eigenvalues of a are:" << std::endl << ces.eigenvalues() << std::endl;
}
```

The eigenvalues are the same (to five significant digits) as those from zgeev:

http://www.nag.com/lapack-ex/node92.html

(Note: Eigen and zgeev order the output eigenvalues differently)